# How to use python dependency injection or hooks with dbt

Tags: python, dbt

Is there a way to use python based hooks with dbt?

I'm using seed data to create dynamic models with jinja but am looking for a bit more python flexibility than with what's available with jinja natively. As a comparison, something along the lines of the way Django views can inject variables into templates.

I'm new to dbt and perhaps approaching this wrong.  Thanks to anyone with help or advice.

Here's an example where I was looking to use python zip and ended up using similar sql logic.  I have a similar need to use python's enumerate. Should I just use sql over python for these types of scenario? I suppose most if not all of this can be achieved with sql (i just happen to be more familiar with python than sql when it comes to this type manipulation).

Current working example using sql:

```
{% set mappings = dbt_utils.get_query_results_as_dict("select 
      CONCAT(my_field, ' AS ', my_alias) AS my_pairs FROM " ~  
      ref('data_seed_schema1_to_schema2') ) %}

SELECT
    {% for map in mappings %}
        {{',\n\t\t'.join(mappings[map]) }}
    {% endfor %}
FROM my_table
```

-->

```
SELECT  
    fooA AS barA,  
    fooB AS barb  
FROM my_table
```

desired python example:

```
{% set mappings = dbt_utils.get_query_results_as_dict("select * FROM " ~ 
      ref('data_seed_schema1_to_schema2') ) %}

# my_zip = [f"{x} AS {y} for x, y in zip(mappings['my_field'], mappings['my_alias'])]


SELECT
    {% for x in my_zip%}
        {{',\n\t\t'.join(x) }}
    {% endfor %}
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Can you give a code example (even pseudocode) of your intentions here?

Comment: As a best practice, I would recommend taking these mappings out of a csv seed and simply encode them in a version controlled model; probably within a staging schema.

You could use a script to generate the SQL file from the mapping. If indeed this is what you are trying to achieve via a macro, why not just use a python script instead?

Comment: You can inject variables as environment variables or --vars flag
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-variables/

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like what you are trying to do is getting your data, processing it in Python, and then getting putting it back in dbt.

We recently released a tool called [fal](https://github.com/fal-ai/fal) which handles this case very well.

The way of doing this with fal and pandas:

```py
# Get the schema_change as a pandas.DataFrame
schema_change = ref('data_seed_schema1_to_schema2')
#   my_field my_alias
# 0     fooA     barA
# 1     fooB     barB

# Build the dictionary necessary to change data column names
change_dict = dict(schema_change.values)
# {'fooA': 'barA', 'fooB': 'barB'}

data = ref('my_table')
#     fooA  fooB
# 0   True     1
# 1  False     2

# Change the data's column names
data = data.rename(columns=change_dict)
#     barA  barB
# 0   True     1
# 1  False     2


# Upload it back to the datawarehouse
write_to_source(data, 'source_name', 'source_table')
```

---

You can do this and other kind of processing not easy or possible in SQL, but with the ease of finding the correct data like from dbt.